# Trying to identify why my car is overheating

Tags: ford, overheating, radiator

**Vehicle 2002 Ford Escape XLT 3.0L 6Cyl**

**Troubleshooting completed**:

- Replaced thermostat and housing
- Coolant Flushed twice
- Bypassed heater core, using 3/4" brass coupling
- Replaced Reservoir
- Sensor

**Parts not replaced**:

- Radiator
- Water Pump (*This is enroute, when it arrives, I will replace it*)

**Symptoms**:

- When coolant was flushed, dark, dark-green fluid including debris
  came out
- Fluid is crystal clear now
- All hoses, besides the heater core hoses, get hot
- Bottom radiator hose is cold, can squeeze and feel the pressure in this hose, not sure if blockage is before the hose (radiator) or after (passed thermostat)
- Pressure builds up in reservoir, causes whistling from overflow tube near reservoir spring-loaded cap
- Reservoir tank is a degas tank, there are no bleed
  valves
- The heater core output hose leads to the bottom of the engine,
  this hose is cold
- Steam coming off engine beneath intake-manifold,
  potential leak from build-up of pressure, cannot identify it
- Fans kick on high 15 minutes after car has been turned on
- Fans are electric powered
- Radiator aluminum, extremely hot

I this point I have tried degassing the coolant system with internal AC on high, this was prior to bypassing the heater core, but cold air came out of both hot and cold settings. My guess that my heater core had blockage, and the same, may result somewhere else.

When I flushed the radiator fluid, I pulled the drain plug from the radiator, I pulled the bottom reservoir hose off and attached a hose to it, turned the hose on high and water was coming out of the drain plug at high rate of speed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Hello, ty! I have tried other forums, but haven;t received any responses to my inquiry =\

Comment: Two more things to consider, the coolant temperature sensor could be defective causing it to over heat - maybe, or it could be that the water pump isn't pushing the coolant through the engine

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you help me. You said that you bypassed the heater core, then later you said no heat is coming out, one the job of the heater core is to blow out warm air in the cabin and two when the ac is on max it'll always blow out cold :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, all that was done priority to bypassing the heater core. In fact I bypass the heater core yesterday, I went to Home Depot and bought three quarter inch brass coupling. I wanted to CF bypassing the heater core would alleviate the issue, but it has not. I also forgot to mention that the sensor has been replaced, I ordered the sensor the water pump and the reservoir all off rockauto.com

Comment: Did you bleed the system right? Bypassing the heater core actually worsens the problem of overheating because the heater core draws heat out of the coolant when then heat in the car is turned on

Comment: There is no bleed valve, I have a degas reservoir, it's supposed to work itself out. The cap to the reservoir is spring loaded, so if the pressure build up, this puts pressure on the spring in the cap, lifts it and lets air out of the overflow tube. I followed this guys instructions to bleeding the air:

https://youtu.be/4gk4xb9aOgE?t=111

The the input tube for the heater core gets hot, but the output tube for the heater core is cold, so there is blockage, running the ac bleed method would not work since the heater core has blockage.

Comment: When your degassing/burping the coolant I personally never turn the ac on high anymore, that wouldn't have any effect, I did the same thing when I started this 2 weeks ago :)  I had to flush it all back out, filtered it, then put it back in and turned the heat valve all the way, I left the fan and the speed setting off, because you just want the coolant valve to the core to open all the way, then leave the cap off and let it run for 20 minutes and then squeeze the top radiator hose, if any air is left it should burp like someone with a case of bad hickups, but air wouldn't cause it to overheat

Comment: Sounds like the water pump is bad, are you getting power to your coolant temperature sensor ?

Comment: @user38183  I tried this, but at some point the radiator fluid boils out splashing like a volcano =\. I did replace the pump yesterday and you wouldn't believe what I found.

[Old Pump 1](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ANCnR2hioWXa4Fah9)
[Old Pump 2](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8ahzXnbnHUwCsps69)
[New Pump 1](https://photos.app.goo.gl/kFTy3DcBgSrTkPrs9)
[New Pump 2](https://photos.app.goo.gl/4ScJDmVdDK8BrqJ47)

Comment: The old pump had metal shards inside, broken off from the old pump. My assumption was the metal shards were the housing to the old pumps propeller, protecting the fins from debris. They were all bent to hell and fell out immediately after I pulled the old pump off. I